# I built a Quiz app I have a problem that sometimes the method of correct answer and incorrect answer are run together. The problem occurs occasionally

Tags: javascript

I built a Quiz app I have a problem that sometimes the method of correct answer and incorrect answer are run together.
**The problem occurs occasionally.**

I will note that the code works fine.
Just the problem I mentioned above that sometimes the methods
this._incorrect () and this._correct ()
Run together at the same time.

```
'use strict';
/** Import */
import harryPotterName from './NamesArray.js';

/**Const */
const btnAll = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
const divPicture = document.querySelector('.divPicture');
const scoreDOM = document.querySelector('.score');

class QuizzGame {
  /*settings */
  #randomNumArr = [
    [0, 1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6, 7],
    [9, 10, 11, 8],
    [12, 13, 14, 15],
    [16, 17, 18, 19],
    [20, 21, 22, 23],
    [24, 25, 26, 27],
  ];

  #score = 5;

  constructor() {
    this.arr = this.#randomNumArr[this._rand()]; // array Destructuring
    this.randInArr = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4); // rand in arr [0,2,3,4] = rand [2]
    this.id = this.arr.at(this.randInArr); // Slice

    btnAll.forEach((btn, i) => {
      btn.setAttribute('data-id', this.arr[i]); // Set Attribute [data-id, i]
      btn.innerHTML = harryPotterName[this.arr[i]];
      btn.addEventListener('click', e => this._ButtonHandler(e));
    });

    this._init();
  }

  _rand() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * this.#randomNumArr.length);
  }

  _randInArr() {
    this.arr = this.#randomNumArr[this._rand()];
    this.randInArr = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4); // rand in arr [0,2,3,4] = rand [2]
    this.id = this.arr.at(this.randInArr); // Slice
  }

  _ButtonHandler(e) {
    console.log(+e.target.dataset.id, this.id);

    if (+e.target.dataset.id !== this.id || this.#score <= 0) this._incorrect(); // incorrect Answer
    if (+e.target.dataset.id === this.id && this.#score > 0) this._correct(); // correct Answer
  }

  _incorrect() {
    console.log('_incorrect');
    scoreDOM.textContent = this.#score <= 0 ? 'you lose' : --this.#score;

    this._randInArr();
    this._nextQuestion(); // next to the Question
    this._showImg(); // render img
  }

  _correct() {
    console.log('_correct');
    scoreDOM.textContent = ++this.#score;

    this._randInArr();
    this._nextQuestion(); // next to the Question
    this._showImg(); // render img
  }

  _nextQuestion() {
    btnAll.forEach((btn, i) => {
      btn.removeAttribute('data-id');
      btn.setAttribute('data-id', this.arr[i]); // Set Attribute [data-id, i]
      btn.innerHTML = harryPotterName[this.arr[i]];
    });
  }

  _showImg() {
    divPicture.innerHTML = `
      <img class="rounded mx-auto d-block" src="images/Players/${this.id}.jpg" />
    `;
  }

  _init() {
    scoreDOM.textContent = this.#score;
    this._showImg();
  }
}

new QuizzGame();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here. Once you have an `incorrect` answer, `this._incorrect()` gets triggered which causes `this.id` to be changed. And after that another condition is being executed, so in this case `this.id` is already changed and it can pass the condition which is checking if the answer is correct.

```
  _ButtonHandler(e) {
    console.log(+e.target.dataset.id, this.id);

    if (+e.target.dataset.id !== this.id || this.#score <= 0) this._incorrect(); // incorrect Answer
    if (+e.target.dataset.id === this.id && this.#score > 0) this._correct(); // correct Answer
  }
```

You need to create a local variable of `this.id` inside your `_ButtonHandler`. In this case, even if `this_incorrect()` is called, it will not mutate `this.id`, and the execution of your `_ButtonHandler` will not depend on side effects.

```
_ButtonHandler(e) {
  let capturedId = this.id // <- HERE    
  console.log(+e.target.dataset.id, this.id);

  if (+e.target.dataset.id !== capturedId || this.#score <= 0) this._incorrect(); // incorrect Answer
  if (+e.target.dataset.id === capturedId  && this.#score > 0) this._correct(); // correct Answer
}
```

Comment: Hey,
thank you for the answer.

But i need to use this.id for _showImg ()
Otherwise it will not show me the picture.
If I put it locally.
And I need it to show me the image immediately notice the init method.

Comment: Use local variable only for your conditions inside `_ButtonHandler`, everywhere else keep `this.id`. Or simply replace two separate `if` conditions with `if ` and `else if`

Comment: I did as you said.
I left this.id global and just created a local variable
this.idLocal = this.id
And it worked.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Most welcome :)